# Can I reach a login prompt on Windows 10?

Tags: windows, windows-10, login, login-screen, username

I have a standalone machine running Windows 10 (19041) with three user accounts:

- VisibleUser1 (standard user, has a password)
- VisibleUser2 (standard user, no password)
- HiddenUser (administrator, has a password)

and a registry entry at HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon\SpecialAccounts\HiddenUser so that 'HiddenUser' is not displayed on the logon page.

When we boot the computer we want to see VisibleUser1 and VisibleUser2 so we can login by clicking on them (this works) and be able to reach a username/password prompt so we can log-in as HiddenUser.

We can't find any key combination to reach a username/password prompt. Is it even possible?

Note: setting the "Interactive logon: Don't display last signed-in" to enabled is not a solution, because Windows will no longer display VisibleUser1 and VisbileUser2.

Comment: Is this Windows Home or Pro? (Windows XP used to have 2x Ctrl+Alt+Del for a username prompt, but I think this no longer works.)

Comment: It's Windows 10 Pro.  Have tried 2x-ctrl-alt-delete and I think you're right.

Comment: Enable the "Other user" option https://www.tenforums.com/attachments/user-accounts-family-safety/109049d1485973748t-two-user-options-login-screen-need-remove-one-img_20161105_235916.jpg

Comment: That will work Ricardo. Any idea how Windows decides whether to show that or not?